# Two cronjobs not working (one to start a process, one to stop a process)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, cron, raspbian

I typed the following into `crontab -e`

```
0 0 * * * bitcoind -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData -daemon
0 6 * * * bitcoin-cli -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData stop
```

I expect this to run `bitcoind -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData -daemon` at 12am every day
and then run `bitcoin-cli -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData stop` at 6am every day.
But the commands do not get executed.
How can I fix this?

---

Output from "cron status":

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-05-03 20:57:33 BST; 58min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 5932 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─5932 /usr/sbin/cron -f

raspberrypi CRON[7608]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
raspberrypi CRON[7615]: (root) CMD (bitcoind -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData -daemon)
raspberrypi CRON[7608]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
raspberrypi cron[5932]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

(As suggested)
I added `>> /tmp/bitcoin-cron.log 2>&1` to the end of each line in cron. 
The log file was showing `/bin/sh: 1: bitcoind: not found`

So I added the full paths to the programs into the PATH like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/bin $ locate bitcoind
/usr/local/bin/bitcoind
pi@raspberrypi:~/bin $ locate bitcoin-cli
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli
pi@raspberrypi:~/bin $ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/bitcoind
pi@raspberrypi:~/bin $ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli
pi@raspberrypi:~/bin $ echo $PATH
/home/pi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin/bitcoind:/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli
```

Tried cron again, and it generated a second line in the log file, which also said `/bin/sh: 1: bitcoind: not found`

Comment: When a cron job fails, you usually get an email on the server addresses to the user whose crontab you have put these commands into. Login as that user and run command `mail` and see if you have any messages and if yes, look at those messages' content. More than likely, `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli` are not in the `PATH` and could not be found. But this is just a guess. You need to figure out the exact cause from those messages. If there are no messages, you need to gain root privilege and look at the `/var/log/cron` file's contents.

Comment: @MelBurslan, Added the output of cron status above.  I get `command not found` when i type `mail` and I get no output from `/var/log/cron` when run as sudo.

Comment: please add `>> /tmp/bitcoin-cron.log 2>&1` to the end of each line in cron. It looks like your mail is not set up so, delivery of failure messages will not happen via email. This way, you will see what transpired each time those two commands ran by inspecting `/tmp/bitcoin-cron.log` file

Comment: @MelBurslan, looks like you were right with your first guest.  Please see `update 2` above.

Comment: now, you just need to add the directory to the PATH, not the executable names. So, your commands will be reduced to one single command on update2 and it will be `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: @MelBurslan, isn't /usr/local/bin already in the PATH?

Comment: When you are running an interactive session, yes, it is more than likely, in your path. Bu t you need to understand, your environment is not the same when you are running something via cron. Actually your `export` command is not going to work in this case. You need to specify the path to the executable in the crontab itself. Such as: `/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData -daemon` and same for the `bitcoin-cli` line.

Comment: @MelBurslan, That did the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to the problem is to modify the entries in cron with the absolute path names. Added cron command logging capability as the machine doesn't have an MTA to send failure notifications, as follows:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/bitcoind -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData -daemon >> ~/bitcoinData/bitcoin-cron.log 2>&1
0 6 * * * /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData stop >> ~/bitcoinData/bitcoin-cron.log 2>&1
```